Reduce Serilog Excessive Logging on HttpClient Calls
I'm using Serilog in my application for all of my logging needs. When I check my logs, I see excessive logs to the effect of:
[11:58:44 INF] Start processing HTTP request GET [url here]
[11:58:44 INF] Sending HTTP request GET [url here]
[11:58:44 INF] Received HTTP response headers after 148.4156ms - 200
[11:58:44 INF] End processing HTTP request after 164.7209ms - 200

This application makes this particular call very often, so my logs are full of these. When I'm scrolling through for an error log, it makes finding them very hard. So basically I'd like to turn off INFO logs, or at least stop HttpClient calls from logging.
I did find this answer, so I tried adding the following to my appsettings.json:
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
    }
  }

But that didn't have any effect, so I'm wondering if there's additional configuration I have to do.
Here's my logger config setup:
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Console()
.WriteTo.File($"logs/log-{DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yy_HH.mm}.log")
.CreateLogger();
and then I just use
services.AddLogging(options => options.AddSerilog(loggerConfig, dispose: true));

to add it. Is there anything else I can do to remove the unwanted logs?

I don't see you reading your config settings from the file.  I suspect you just need to add the consumption of the file to your CreateLogger() Also, you can try writing your loggerConfig object attributes to file or console and see if they are set correctly.

Okay so it looks like I was able to solve this with filters, using this specific configuration:
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Filter.ByExcluding(logEvent =>
        logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("SourceContext", out var sourceContext) &&
        sourceContext.ToString().Contains("System.Net.Http.HttpClient") &&
        logEvent.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File($"logs/log-{DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yy_HH.mm}.log")
    .CreateLogger();

This appears to be filtering the Info level logs from System.Net.Http.HttpClient.

The overrides you need will depend on the .NET version you're using; the best way to tinker with this and try out variations will be to add the minimum level overrides in C# code.
Using Serilog in ASP.NET Core in .NET 8, it looks like this:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    ...

Serilog uses a different configuration section from the "Logging" one; Serilog's is called "Serilog" and has different minimum level override syntax:
{
    "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning",
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "Warning"
            }
        }
    }
}

The overrides are grabbed from this how-to, which has some further information on cleaning up ASP.NET Core logging output.
